# A javascript function to be executable on a specific screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible?

I have the following javascript function

```
    <a onclick="execute()">Click here</a>

    function execute(){
      //code goes here
    }
```

I would like that the onclick event to be only active when the screen size is below 768, so it's only relevant on mobile devices and so on.

Is it possible? and how do you achieve this?

Comment: If you aren't linking anywhere, don't use an <a> tag - use a different node else you'd need to `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Bigger question, if the logic shouldn't happen if the screen size is below `768`, why is the link available for them to click it in those resolutions?  Having something that says "click here" that doesn't do anything, is highly concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function execute(){
   if(screen.width <= 768) {
       //code goes here
     }

}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

Answer (score 2):

It's totally possible. You'd probably want to do it in the execute function, otherwise when someone clicks on a larger size, there would be a ReferenceError (execute is not defined).

```
function execute () {
  var width = window.innerWidth
  if (width >= 768) return
  // rest of code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also use a media query with CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)